# Automatically load associated rows

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

i have a simple posting system with ability to add special fields to blog posts (something like `custom fields` in wordpress). Here are my models:

```
<?php
# Node.php
class Model_Node extends ORM
{
    protected $_belongs_to = array('category' => array());
    protected $_has_one    = array('path' => array());
    protected $_has_many   = array('fields' => array());
    (...)
}

# Field.php
class Model_Field extends ORM
{
    protected $_belongs_to = array('node' => array());
    (...)
}
?>
```

For now, when i'm loading `Node` model with `factory()`, i don't have a direct access to `Fields` associated to my `Node`; i need to use `$node->fields->find_all()`. I was wondering - is there a possibility to automatically load the associated fields when querying a `Node` from database?

Let's say i want to use it that way:

```
<?php
$node = ORM::factory('node');
$nodes = $node->find(1);

// as you can see, i don't want to use separated query for getting `fields`.
foreach( $node->fields as $field )
{
  echo $field->content;
}
?>
```

I've seen that i can use `$_load_with` model property or `->with('fields')` but those two solutions returns empty result. Have you any advices for me? :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: `with()` works only for a one-to-one relationships, so you can autoload `$node->category`, but not `$node->fields`.

Comment: and there is completely no way to autoload one-to-many relations ?

Comment: You can extend `find()` method in your Node model, so it will load all relationships with a main row. But I'd preffer to use 2 separated queries (easy to manage, easy caching etc).

Comment: Yeah, i've tried that but it breaks my `find()` function because, probably, i'm doing it wrong. Here is my attempt: http://pastebin.com/nSSvuAKG but after adding this code to my model, using `->find()` returns nothing. Btw - please post your last comment as a Answer cause i'll probably mark it as a solution (when i'll make this `find()` work) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my update for your `find()` extension: http://pastebin.com/T5dsyNPw. Haven't tested it, but it *should* work.